# How to insert newline in reactstrap tooltip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactstrap

My project has a reusable tooltip component that utilizes [reactstrap tooltip](https://bit.dev/reactstrap/reactstrap/uncontrolled-tooltip) to show the tooltip. The usage is shown below

```
import { UncontrolledTooltip } from 'reactstrap';

const Tooltip = ({
  target,
  title,
  trigger,
  position,
  delay,
  size,
  boundariesElement,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={TooltipStyles.tooltip}>
      {title.length && target && (
        <UncontrolledTooltip
          cssModule={TooltipStyles}
          placement={position}
          target={target}
          trigger={trigger}
          delay={delay}
          defaultOpen={false}
          popperClassName={TooltipStyles.tooltipFade}
          innerClassName={classNames({
            [TooltipStyles.textSizeSmall]: size === 'small',
            [TooltipStyles.textSizeDefault]: size === 'default',
            [TooltipStyles.textSizeLarge]: size === 'large',
          })}
          boundariesElement={boundariesElement}
        >
          {title}
        </UncontrolledTooltip>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to create a multi-line tooltip to show a list of items. Basically, I want the `title` prop to render a multi-line string.  Can someone please guide me on how to do this?

I tried sending HTML in the title prop but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Send title as html, add `<br />` tags.

Below code show tooltip in 2 lines

```
<p>Somewhere in here is a <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline', color:'blue'}} href='#' id='UncontrolledTooltipExample'>tooltip</span>.</p>
      <UncontrolledTooltip placement='right' target='UncontrolledTooltipExample'>
        Hello <br />world!
      </UncontrolledTooltip>
      </div>
```

[image]

> I tried sending HTML in the title prop but it doesn't work. :(

You need to send it as JSX not as html string

`title='Hello<br />World'` will not work

`title={<>Hello<br />World</>}` should work

Use below code in your example and see it working

```
import React from 'react';
import Tooltip from '@bit/reactstrap.reactstrap.tooltip';

 class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      tooltipOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      tooltipOpen: !this.state.tooltipOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <link
          rel='stylesheet'
          href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        />
        <p>Somewhere in here is a <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline', color:'blue'}} href='#' id='TooltipExample'>tooltip</span>.</p>
        <Tooltip placement='right' isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target='TooltipExample' toggle={this.toggle}>
          {this.props.title}
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default <Example title={<>Line one<br />Line 2<br />Line3</>} />
```

[image]

Comment: If I send jsx, the tooltip doesn't show up :( tried using `title={<>Hello<br />World</>}` but the tooltip stops working

Comment: @JakeCano Try changing `title.length` to `title`